# Relationship between the induced measure on an orbit and Hausdorff measure on the orbit

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, locally-compact-groups, hausdorff-measure, haar-measure

**Assumptions**

- Let $G$ be a locally compact group that acts continuously on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- Let $\mu$ be a right Haar measure on $G$.
- Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ ($m < n$) be a Lipchitz function whose $m$-dimensional Jacobian $J_m F$ does not vanish on a compact set $A \subseteq  \mathbb{R^n}$.
- Let $Gx = \{gx : g \in G \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the orbit of a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
- Assume that $F(Gx) = F(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $g \in G$.
- Assume that $F(Gx)=F(Gy)$ implies $Gx=Gy$ for all $x,y \in G$
- Fix $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and note that $Gx_0 = F^{-1}(F(x_0))$.
- Let $H_{x_0}$ denote the restriction of $n-m$ dimensional Hausdorff measure to the set $Gx_0 = F^{-1}(F(x_0))$.
- Let $\nu_{x_0}$ be the measure on $Gx_0 = F^{-1}(F(x_0))$ induced by $\mu$:
  $$
  \int_{Gx_0} f(x) d\nu_{x_0}(x) = \int_{G} f(gx_0) d\mu(g)
  $$

**Question:**

What is the relationship between $\nu_{x_0}$ and $H_{x_0}$? Are they absolutely continuous with respect to each other? If so, what properties does the density have? Are they constant multiples of each other?

**Edit/Update:**

user120527 has shown below that $G$ acting continuously on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not enough to get $\nu_{x_0} \ll H_{x_0}$, and suggests additional regularity of the action as the fix. Since the action in the construction is asymmetric, I wonder whether the absolute continuity can be obtained by making the action symmetric.

In other words, what happens if we add the following assumption?

- $G$ acts continuously on $\mathbb{R}$, and $G$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^n$ pointwise: $gx = (g x_1,\ldots,g x_n)$.

I ask this as a separate question here: [Take 2: Relationship between the induced measure on an orbit and Hausdorff measure on the orbit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704809/take-2-relationship-between-the-induced-measure-on-an-orbit-and-hausdorff-measu)

Comment: I see several problems here. $\nu_{x_0}$ is well defined if the map $g\mapsto gx_0$ is proper, but if there is a large stabilizer, $g\mapsto f(gx_0)$ may not be compactly supported, and its integral wrt $\mu$ undefined/infinite.

Comment: Also, if the action is only continuous,  it is easy to give counterexamples. If for example $G=\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable flow, if you reparametrize the flow in a non-differentiable way, then $\nu_{x_0}$ changes drastically (i.e. in a non-absolutely continuous manner).

Comment: @user120527 Is it really a problem if the integral on the right is infinite? I mean, if $dx$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ we still get a perfectly good measure by defining, say, 
$\int f(x) dm(x) = \int f(x+1)dx$

Comment: Usually one consider only Radon measures (ie finite on compact sets). So the integral of a continuous compactly supported function should be finite

Comment: @user120527 Ah, so your concern is that the induced measure $\nu_{x_0}$ might not be finite on compact sets. I agree that could happen.

Comment: @user120527 I'm not so familiar with differentiable flow. Could you flesh out the details of your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's check an example.

Choose $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a increasing homeomorphism (to be chosen later).
Let $G=\mathbb{R}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$ the following way:
$$t \cdot (x,y)= (\phi(\phi^{-1}(x)+t),y).$$
That is simply a conjugacy with the action by translation on the first coordinate. The thing is, thanks to the conjugacy by $\phi$, the points may move to the right in a weird, non-differentiable way.

The orbits $G(x_0,y_0)$ are simply the horizontal lines. Define $F(x,y)=y$. Then $H_{(x_0,y_0)}$ is simply the Lebesgue measure on the horizontal line $y=y_0$.

Now let us compute $\nu_{(x_0,y_0)}$ :
$$\int_{(x,y_0)} f(x) d\nu_{(x_0,y_0)}(x)= \int_\mathbb{R} f(\phi(\phi^{-1}(x_0)+t),y_0)dt= \int_\mathbb{R} f(\phi(s),y_0)ds=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y_0) d\phi_*\mathcal{L}(x),$$
by putting $s=\phi^{-1}(x_0)+t$, with $\phi_*\mathcal{L}$ the image measure under $\phi$ of the Lebesgue measure $\mathcal{L}$.

Now the question is : is $\phi_*\mathcal{L}$ absolutely continuous wrt to $\mathcal{L}$, when $\phi$ is a homeomorphism ? The answer is yes is $\phi$ has some regularity ($C^1$ is okay,  Lipschitz would probably do), but if the homeomorphism is only Holder (or worse), no in general. For an horrible example, consider your favorite measure $\mu$ such that

- $\mu(0,+\infty)=+\infty, \mu(-\infty,0)=+\infty$
- $\mu$ is singular to the Lebesgue measure,
- $\mu$ has no atom
- $\mu$ has full support in $\mathbb{R}$

Then it can be realised as the image measure $\phi_*\mathcal{L}$ for some $\phi$.

The construction goes as follows: for $t>0$, put $\psi(t)=\mu(0,t)$, and for $t<0$, $\psi(t)=-\mu(t,0)$. $\psi$ is continuous (because no atoms), $\psi$ is strictly increasing (because full support), and the limits are $\pm\infty$ at $\pm \infty$. So it is an homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\phi$ be its inverse. Then one can check that $\phi_*\mathcal{L}=\mu$.

Comment: This is very nice. Thank you. The asymmetry of the group action here makes me wonder whether the absolute continuity can be obtained by banning such asymmetric group actions. I'm going to add an edit to the question, but if you feel like it is "moving the goal posts," then I am happy to make it a new question.

Comment: I decided to ask this follow-up as a separate question.